# Where is the folder that Termux defaults to?

Tags: applications, storage, termux

The Termux app is a terminal emulator. If I create a file or a folder there, and then use another file explorer app to browse my device, where can I find these files?

Comment: `/data/data/com.termux/files/home `  ??

Comment: If you're looking for other folders, they're probably in `/storage/emulated/0`. For example `/storage/emulated/0/Download` (no "s") for your downloads or `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM` for your images.

Comment: @beeshyams that is what I got from the pwd command, but is it mounted? I didn't think apps could get access to the root directory, and terminal would have to read it to find out its pos. I assumed that terms mounted the `data` folder somewhere and cannot see past the mount.

Comment: I was right. `data` is mounted inside `Android` folder, accessible from inside the file explorer..

Answer (score 70):

You don't need to root your device. All you need to do is run the following command on a non-rooted (or rooted) device to allow termux to access your existing directories, particularly `/storage/emulated/0`:

```
termux-setup-storage
```

this creates a new directory in termux, `~/storage`, which contains simlinks to `/storage/emulated/0` and can be accessed by a standard gui file manager.

You will need to grant file access to termux when prompted after you run the command.

See [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/166595/termux-how-do-i-create-a-directory-of-files-accessible-outside-of-termux/166637#166637).

Comment: This worked!  Though I'll just point out to anyone who didn't pick up on it, that it's not the **~/storage** directory itself that is `/storage/emulated/0`, but that location is rather the symlink **~/storage/shared**.  Hence putting things into `~/storage` directory wouldn't help you access the files.

Comment: Where can I access that file in USB mode? I need to edit the extra key config file. I don't have ctrl key now, can't do much via termux

Comment: This worked for me also after I ran `pkg install termux-am` as mentioned from this [issue](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/3647#issuecomment-1763556222). This [comment](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/3647#issuecomment-1868384046) also mentions another install that I believed I installed once too that has helped with this issue as well

Answer (score 10):

The default directory is: `/data/data/com.termux/files/home`.

Since Termux supports bash commands, user can run `pwd` to print current working directory.

Note: `pwd` is an acronym of **p**rint **w**orking **d**irectory.

---

Reference: [Unix.SE - How to get current working directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188182/how-to-get-current-working-directory)

Comment: Thanks... But my data directory is empty. My phone is not rooted... Does that matter?

Comment: @Maxcot Unfortunately, yes. The `/data/` folder is only accessible to all if the phone is rooted. By default, only Termux can write & read that folder.

Comment: @Maxcot you might want to copy (or move, but becareful) them to `/sdcard` if you want. Refer to [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643848/copy-files-from-one-directory-into-an-existing-directory)

Comment: [Termux help](https://termux.com/storage.html) may provide a way out ( not tried by me)

Comment: What I don't understand is why I have access to the folders through termux, but not through any other app like ES File Explorer. It's like the permissions are dependant on the app, not the user.

Comment: @Maxcot Sorry for late reply. Yes, it's because each running app is sandboxed for security reason so that other apps cannot read/write other apps' data directly.

Answer (score 8):

Provided that you don't want to root your phone, it is possible to change permission for Termux (Settings->Applications->Termux->Permissions) and enable the Storage permission.

This way you are granted access to phone and sdcard storage and you can use it as superuser (mv, ls and other commands work as intended) in the application.

So, you can move or copy the files you need into internal storage.

Comment: You may also need to run `termux-setup-storage` in Termux to gain access to the SD Card or Internal Storage

Answer (score 3):

You can query the `$HOME` variable to find the "default folder" regardless of the terminal app you're using:

```
$ echo $HOME
/data/data/com.termux/files/home
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You can access the files inside the termux folder by simply doing this. (Without using any third-party app/rooting your device)

Step 1: Go to Downloads on your Device

[image]

Step 2: Go to the Appbar

[image]

Step 3: Scroll down till you find Termux

[image]

Step 4: Click on Termux and you can see your files

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Termux has its default directory that's inaccessible to newbies. To verify this, on the CLI, type

```
$ pwd
```

and `data/data/com.termux/files/home` should appear.

To be able to manipulate your Android directory from Termux, on your Android device, go to Settings - Apps - Termux - Permissions - tap "Storage" on.

Now on the CLI, in Termux, type

```
$ cd /storage/emulated/0
$ pwd
```

and `/storage/emulated/0` should appear.

You can as well create a new file in your local storage,  type

```
$ echo hello world > MyFirstTermuxFile.txt
```

That's it. You can now play with your local device storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can touch it on `data/data/com.termux/files/home`. That's the default main directory of Termux.

It's impossible to find the file that you've created on Termux main directory as I mentioned above on your phone because it's not rooted on any device.

It works as sort of a server. By thereon `data/data/com.texmux/files/home`, which is the default main directory of Termux, you can already browse files, create files, manipulating them the same sort you're using your file manager

Answer (score 1):

You can view it easily with Material file manager.
https://www.learntermux.tech/2020/10/Termux-File-Manager.html
Here is a guide I found useful to me.

Comment: Hi, whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Consider [edit]ing to summarize the content and/or expand the answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/250757)