# Termux - How do I create a directory of files accessible outside of Termux?

Tags: storage, terminal, termux

I discovered that the files and directory that are created in (default) Termux, are not accessible to other apps on non-rooted phones.

[Where is the folder that Termux defaults to?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/166538/where-is-the-folder-that-termux-defaults-to)

How do I set it to use a folder / filespace that I can access through an app like ES File Explorer?

Or perhaps slightly differently, how in Termus would I change to, let's say, the default "Download" folder?

Cheers.

Comment: You can try method mentioned in app [help](https://termux.com/storage.html)

Comment: To change to the default **Download** folder, use `cd /storage/emulated/0/Download`.

Comment: You can also access the default storage location. Navigate to the folder `Android` and then to `data`. From there you should be staring at `com.termux`.

Answer (score 30):

From within Termux itself, you can change the current directory to the internal storage, by means of

```
cd /storage/emulated/0
```

or

```
cd /sdcard
```

followed by enter. After that, create a new directory by using

```
mkdir Directory
```

and replace `Directory` with a name of your choice. You'll then have a new directory in your device's internal storage, whose data you'll be able to access with any file manager.

---

### Notes concerning Marshmallow and above

If your device is running Android 6 or newer, you'll need to run the command

```
termux-setup-storage
```

from within Termux, and then accept the request to write to the storage, in order for Termux to be able to perform directory and file creation.

The `termux-setup-storage` command creates a new directory in your `$HOME` or `~/` directory named `storage`. This new directory contains a few symlinks to `/storage/emulated/0` listed below:

```
dcim -> /storage/emulated/0/DCIM
downloads -> /storage/emulated/0/Download
external-1 -> /storage/external_sd/Android/data/com.termux/files
movies -> /storage/emulated/0/Movies
music -> /storage/emulated/0/Music
pictures -> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures
shared -> /storage/emulated/0
```

Therefore, you can run the following commands to create `/storage/emulated/0/Directory` described above with a little less typing now:

```
cd ~/storage/shared
mkdir Directory
```

Comment: To whosoever edited my answer, good job.

Comment: If you're using (Android) termux on a Chromebook, the external storage doesn't appear to be available (in the current version of Android for Chromebook). I used the built-in file explorer to copy my files to 'Downloads', and then, in termux, I could copy them from `/sdcard/Download` to `$HOME`.

Comment: According to [Termux wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-setup-storage) Android 11 users may face to a **Permission denied** error after all this steps. Refer to the wiki for workaround.

Answer (score 1):

See https://wiki.termux.com/index.php?search=Storage for the newest information about using storage in Termux.  https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-setup-storage is the prerequisite.  Use it first.  To share data see https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Sharing_Data for more information.