# Moving default folder Termux with content to downloads in Android 7

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7, termux

This is what I need;
[Termux - How do I create a directory of files accessible outside of Termux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/166595/termux-how-do-i-create-a-directory-of-files-accessible-outside-of-termux/182542#182542)

I have my Tiddlywiki running on node.js in Termux. My problem is that Termux stores all files in the default folder. This way I can not let Dropbox backup. Can someone help me moving the default folder (with content) to, for example, Downloads? Or what is the best directory in my case? I spent years working on my Wiki and I'm afraid of making mistakes.

Android 7 (Nougat)

I installed my Tiddlywiki to this example: http://tiddlywiki.com/static/Installing%2520TiddlyWiki%2520on%2520Node.js.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129415/discussion-on-question-by-jan-moving-default-folder-termux-with-content-to-downl).

Answer (score 0):

See https://wiki.termux.com/index.php?search=Storage for the newest information about using storage in Termux.  https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-setup-storage is the prerequisite.  Use it first.  To share data see https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Sharing_Data for more information. Save your data to external storage in `~/storage/external` which should be a link to `Android/data/com.termux/files` on your external SD card, and will be accessible from both Termux and Android.